# DirectoryInfo().GetFileSystemInfos() - how to avoid hidden folders?

Tags: c#, filesysteminfo

If I do this:

```
var entries = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Folder1")
                   .GetFileSystemInfos("test*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

when I have a folder structure like this, where the "HiddenFolder" is hidden but the "test.txt" file is not hidden:

```
C:\Folder1\
C:\Folder1\HiddenFolder\
C:\Folder1\HiddenFolder\test.txt
```

Then how can I code to NOT get the "test.txt" file?

(You might think that GetFileSystemInfos would skip hidden folders, but it doesn't.)

#### Here is a partial solution

This code strips out hidden files and folders, but doesn't handle a non-hidden file inside a hidden folder!

```
  var includeLocalFolderNames = true; // to include folder names in the list

  var hiddenFolders = new List<FileSystemInfo>();
  return entries
    .Where(entry =>
      {
        // skip if this entry is hidden, or it is in a hidden folder

        var isHidden = (entry.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) != 0;
        if (isHidden)
        {
          hiddenFolders.Add(entry);
          return false;
        }
        return !hiddenFolders.Any(fsi => entry.FullName.StartsWith(fsi.FullName));
      })
    .Where(entry =>
      {
        // include folder names if requested...

        if (includeLocalFolderNames) return true;
        return (entry.Attributes & FileAttributes.Directory) == 0;
      })
    .Select(entry => {
        // do something...
        return entry.Name;
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

Certainly not the most optimal and/or elegant solution.

```
var root = new DirectoryInfo(path);
var nonHiddenDirectories =
    root.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(
        d => (d.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) == 0).ToArray();
var nonHiddenFiles =
    nonHiddenDirectories.SelectMany(d => d.GetFiles()).Where(
        f => (f.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) == 0);
```